# unsigned integers in C

Tags: c, unsigned-integer

While i am running the program below it outputs like 109876543210-1-2-3-4-5-6-78-9-10-11-12-and s0 on. Why so? What is the concept of unsigned integer?

```
 main ()
   {
      unsigned int i;
       for (i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
                 printf ("%d", i);
   }
```

Comment: Btw the difference between signed int and unsigned int in c is for example in the way it does bit shifts, which effectively means wheter it uses sal/sar or shl/shr instructions. Else the number in the register looks the same.

Comment: @stupid_idiot, also it affects comparison, multiplication (mul/imul), division (div/idiv) and propagation to larger types. Maybe something else, not quite sure.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this question so it should not be closed as "not a real question". But due to the very basic nature, perhaps it is "too localized".

Answer (score 9):

Unsigned integers are always non-negative, that is greater than or equal to 0. When you subtract 1 from 0 in an unsigned integer type you end up with MAX_INT.

Therefore, your for loop will never terminate.

However, you need to use "%u" not "%d" in your printf if you want it to print the unsigned value rather than the signed value.

Comment: I think you mean non-negative. `0U` is definitely not positive. :-)

Comment: @R.. Indeed. I'll edit, duh :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `%d` format string treats the substituted value as `int`, which is signed.

Answer (score 2):

You use `%d`, so printf interprets the value as signed.
Comparison to zero (>=0) of unsigned is always true.

So, while values are from 10 to 0, the output is ok (109876543210). After that the value becomes huge positive (maximum value, for 32bit int it is `0xFFFFFFFF`). Comparison to 0 is true, so the loop continues. But in `printf` `0xFFFFFFFF` produces `-1` since `%d` is used. Then the loop continues to `0xFFFFFFFE` which is `-2` but still `>= 0` as unsigned.

Use `%u`.

Comment: yes here is this is the program and running on linux #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 unsigned int i;
       for (i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
                 printf ("%d", i);
return 0;
}

Answer (score 2):

> Why so?

Because your program has an undefined behavior (using `%d` which is for `int` to print an `unsigned`) - so you can expect anything to happen.

Why the infinite loop? Because an `unsigned int` is always `>= 0`.

> What is the concept of unsigned integer?

It's an... **unsigned** integer. A whole number which is non-negative.

Comment: @Virgile There is no conversion from `unsigned` to `int` in the statement `printf("%d", u);` any more than there is a conversion from `float` to `int` in the statement `printf("%d", f);`. 6.3.1.3 does not apply, and 7.19.6.1:8 says that the argument corresponding to `%d` should be an `int`.

Comment: For a normal function call, a conversion would occur, but you're right, variadic functions behave differently, and 7.19.6.1§9 makes it clear that this is UB. I'm thus deleting the original comment.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` can't know the type of the variable you give it, all it gets is the value (the bits themselves). You have to tell it how to interpret that value, and with `%d` you tell it to interpret it as a signed integer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "%d" with printf() which is the format specifier for a signed integer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%u` as a [format specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) in the printf, otherwise the value is casted to `int`.

Comment: @sixlettervariables haha sorry I meant `%u`

Answer (score 0):

The declaration `unsigned integer` instructs the compiler to use unsigned operations on the variable. For example, the `>>` operator has different behavior on unsigned integers vs signed (specifically, whether it should preserve the sign bit).

To print an unsigned integer, you should use the `%u` formatting.

Comment: when using '%u' in outputs like 10987654321042949672954294967294429496729342949672924294967291429496729... what does it it mean.i tried only to print from 10 to 0 unsigned numbers

Comment: Since you have no delimiters between your prints, what you actually see there is the numbers - 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4967295,4294967294,4294967293... the numbers after and including the 11th number are due to your exit condition not being filled (unsigned integers are always >=0, so when you decrease them from 0 they roll over - you can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow))

Answer (score 0):

Signed integers (we'll use 16 bit) range from -32768 to 32767 (0x8000 to 0x7FFF) while *unsigned* integers range from 0 to 65535 (0x0000 to 0xFFFF).  So unsigned integers cannot have negative values, which is why your loop never terminates.  However, you have told the print program to format the output *as if* it were **signed** (`%d`) so that you see the numbers formatted as negative values in your output.  At some level, everything in a computer is just a string of bits that needs interpretation and your code example uses two different interpretations of the same bit patterns ... your unsigned int.

Comment: Don't make assumptions about the bit width of `unsigned` and `int`.

Comment: No assumption on my part, that's why I said "we'll use 16 bit" as an _example_